# C: Ignoring a value while scanning an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm analyzing an array and, using an struct to save the position and the value of each item, I want to get the three minimum values of this array. The problem with this is that I've to ignore a value, '-5' in this case. And if I try to ignore this value, the index messes up and I don't know how to do it.

This is my try:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
typedef struct pair {
        int value, column;
    } Pair;
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Pair data_pair[8];

    int row[8] = {0, 3, 1, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int i=0;i<8;++i){
        if (row[i] != -5){ // Ignore the value -5 from the array
              data_pair[i].value = row[i];
              data_pair[i].column = i;
        }    
    }

    printf("\n\nThe three minimum values of this line are:");
    qsort(data_pair, 8, sizeof(Pair), cmp);
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("\nvalue = %d, column = %d", data_pair[i].value, data_pair[i].column);

    return 0;
}

 int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
     Pair *pa = (Pair *)a;
     Pair *pb = (Pair *)b;
     return pa->value - pb->value; }
```

This is the exit I'm having:

> The three minimum values of this line are:
>   value = 0, column = 0
>   value = 0, column = 0
>   value = 1, column = 4

When the desired solution is:

> The three minimum values of this line are:
>   value = 0, column = 0
>   value = 1, column = 2
>   value = 1, column = 4

What I'm doing wrong? I would like to have a solution just changing some parts of the exposed code. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `data_pair` defined?

Comment: Remove `#include <cstdlib>`, `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` to make it C.

Comment: Why not just sort the original values, then spin through and toss out the -5 as you list the results?

Comment: I missed the definition of data_pair, it's now added to the code. The code works ok, this is just a summary of what I'm doing so you can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Where is defined `i` in for loops ?

Comment: Hint:  You don't need to sort anything.  Can be done by just scanning and keeping track of the3 lowest values encountered so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (row[i] != -5){ // Ignore the value -5 from the array
    data_pair[i].value = row[i];
    data_pair[i].column = i;
} else {// add
    data_pair[i].value = INT_MAX;//#include <limits.h>
    data_pair[i].column = i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue at hand stems from using a shared index `i` and sorting the array regardless of how many items you actually have in the array (e.g. passing `8` unconditionally as the size).

By not setting the values at all indexes in `data_pair`, you're sorting some garbage results in the mix!

So you can use a second indexer with `data_pair` to help filter the results:

```
/* somewhere above: int j; */
for (i=0, j=0;i<8;++i){
    if (row[i] != -5){ // Ignore the value -5 from the array
        data_pair[j].value = row[i];
        data_pair[j].column = i;
        j++; /* indexes data_pair */
    }    
}
```

Now `j` will contain the count of found `Pair`s in `data_pair`s:

```
/* j substitutes for an explicit 8 */
qsort(data_pair, j, sizeof(Pair), cmp);
```