# skip/ignore array index that contain value in c

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

My goal is to create a C function that finds the minimum value of an array and set it to zero. So far, my function does that but I would like it to ignore/skip indexes that are already zero.

```
void find_minimum(double a[], int n) {

    int i, index;
    double low;    

    index = 0;
    low = a[0];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if ( a[i] < low && a[i] != 0.0) {
            low = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    a[index] = 0.0;      
}
```

I also tried using a `continue` statement like this:

```
void find_minimum(double a[],  int n) {

    int i, index;
    double low;

    index = 0;
    low = a[0];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {

        if(a[i] == 0.0){
          continue;
        }
        if ( a[i] < low) {
            low = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    a[index] = 0.0;
}
```

What am I missing or messing up?

Comment: Do format your code properly and be careful about floating-point aritimetic errors.

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens if `a[0]` is already `0`? (I am assuming all your numbers are positive)

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: You have three possibilities: (1) minimal value is greater than zero; (2) minimal value is less than zero; (3) minimal value equals zero. In each possibility you have to deal with floating point arithmetic errors. Further on, it is not wise to initialize minimum to be equal to the first element of the array. I think you should re-work your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651939/c-ignoring-a-value-while-scanning-an-array?rq=1

Comment: @user3078414 Thanks for your suggestion. Your tip about not initializing minimum to be equal to the first element of the array works

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, your code ignores case when `a[0]` is zero. Try assign to low some constant like DOUBLE_MAX and iterate through whole array instead (`i = 0` in `for` initialization statement instead of `i = 1`).

```
void find_minimum(double a[], int n) {

    int i, index;
    double low;    

    index = 0;
    low = DOUBLE_MAX;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ( a[i] < low && a[i] != 0.0) {
            low = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    a[index] = 0.0;      
}
```

Comment: Assuming anything important is using the pre-zeroed value (not the case in the MCVE, but likely in real code), you should probably initialize `index` to `-1`, and check for that after the loop before setting anything to `0.0`. In the MCVE, you'll just rezero index 0 over and over, but it won't be distinguishable from the case where index 0 contained the lowest non-zero value vs. the whole array already being zero. Example case would be If the real code `return`-ed the index with the lowest non-zero value, and it was important to know if the value was really non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your minimum finder from the code which changes the data. You might need to find the minimum somewhere else for different purposes as well. Also, you find `low`, yet, you set the element at index to 0.

```
void find_minimum(double a[], int n) {

    int i, index;
    double low;    

    index;
    low = DOUBLE_MAX;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i]) && (a[i] < low)) {
            low = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return low;      
}

//...
int main() {
    //...
    a[find_minimum(a, n)] = 0;
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DOUBLE_MAX`, as suggested in other posts, you need to have some prior information of maximum possible value in the input array.

But using the below code, you can solve this problem without any such prior information. 
Read the in-line comments:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5    //  change the array size as per your requirement

void find_minimum_set_zero(double a[]) {

    int i, index;
    double low;

    index = 0;
    low = a[index];

    while(low == 0.0 && index < SIZE){    // This will make sure "low" is non-zero
        index++;
        low = a[index];
    }

    for (i = index+1; i < SIZE; i++) {    // This loop starts with "index+1"
        if ( (a[i] < low) && a[i] ) {
            low = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    a[index] = 0.0;
}


int main(){

    double a[SIZE];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i < SIZE; i++){
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }

    find_minimum_set_zero(a);

    for(i=0;i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%lf ", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Sample Input (first line) and Output (second line):*

```
99 98 95 96 97
99.000000 98.000000 0.000000 96.000000 97.000000

0 99 98 96 95
0.000000 99.000000 98.000000 96.000000 0.000000

99 0 98 0 97
99.000000 0.000000 98.000000 0.000000 0.000000

91 99 0 97 0
0.000000 99.000000 0.000000 97.000000 0.000000
```

*PS:* I changed the name of your function from `find_minimum` to `find_minimum_set_zero` just to improve readability.